# Как делать регидрацию при использовании nextjs и mobx?

Tags: nextjs, mobx

Не понимаю почему на next 13 версии, react-dom 18, react 18, useEffect срабатывает не при первом рендере.
Приходится писать костыли в виде хука `useIsFirstRender`, для того что бы это работало:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    const data = await productListStore.fetchProductsFilters(query)
    productListStore.setProductsFilter(data)
    return {
        props: {
            initialData: data,
        },
    }
}
const function useIsFirstRender(callback = () => {}) {
    const isFirst = useRef(true)

    if (isFirst.current) {
        isFirst.current = false
        callback()
        return true
    }

    return isFirst.current
}
const Page = ({ initialData }) => {
    useIsFirstRender(() => {
        productListStore.setProductsFilter(initialData)
    })
    // render jsx...
}
export default observer(Page)
```

Может кто подскажет адекватный способ работы с этим, в проекте большое количество сторов.

Comment: Что такое "регидрация"?

Comment: При вызове метода getServerSideProps данные в стор записываются на стороне сервера. Далее рендериться html на стороне сервера с данными из стора, html летит на клиент. На клиенте уже данных в сторе нет, и необходимо их как то прокидывать повторно в стор, что продемонстрировано в моём примере. На клиенте происходит сравнение, html с сервера и того что отрендерилось на клиенте, расхождений быть не должно.
https://habr.com/ru/post/515100/

Comment: Меня заинтересовал сам термин "регидрация". Что он означает для тебя?

Comment: В данном контексте, синхронизация начального стейта с сервером.

Comment: Стандартно считается нормальным подгружать данные с сервера в хуке `useEffect()`. Если не указывать список зависимостей - он выполнит функцию один раз при создании, после смонтирования элемента в документ. Чем тебя такой вариант не устраивает?

Comment: Нужен SSR для SEO маркетплейса.
При использовании в react 18 useEffect срабатывает только 3-4 рендеру. Из-за чего возникает ошибка гидратации.

Comment: Как по мне так это очень плохая идея — синхрронизация стейта серверной и на клиентской части, потому что потенциально наличием багов, при SSR стейт лучше хранить на серевере а на клиенте делать вывод данных. Там где два "источника истины" — всегда какой-то будет отставать.

Comment: Ну представь, есть у тебя страница с фильтрами товаров, нужно что бы все фильтры записывались в параметры url и при вызове страницы, сервер должен возвращать данные под полученные параметры. При изменении фильтров на клиенте, должен формироваться url с параметрами, которые сервер должен уметь обрабатывать. Речь идет о начальной синхронизации, когда страница загружается впервые, данные передаются на страницу и обновляют стейт.

Answer (score 0):

В React 18 по умолчанию включен экспериментальный режим startTransition, который позволяет оптимизировать рендеринг и улучшить производительность. Одним из изменений является то, что эффекты useEffect не выполняются сразу после рендеринга компонента, а ставятся в очередь на выполнение. Это связано с тем, что startTransition может отложить некоторые изменения состояния, чтобы позволить браузеру выполнить другие задачи, такие как рендеринг анимации или пользовательских действий.

Если вы хотите, чтобы эффект useEffect выполнялся немедленно после первого рендеринга компонента, вы можете использовать второй аргумент useEffect, который определяет зависимости эффекта. Если этот массив зависимостей пустой, эффект будет выполняться только при первом рендеринге компонента.

В вашем случае, вы можете попробовать использовать следующий код:

```
const Page = ({ initialData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    productListStore.setProductsFilter(initialData)
  }, []) // <-- пустой массив зависимостей

  // render jsx...
}

export default observer(Page)
```

Если вы используете useEffect с асинхронными операциями, такими как fetch, вы можете увидеть другое поведение: эффект может не выполняться немедленно после первого рендеринга компонента, но начнет выполняться после того, как будет завершен fetch. В этом случае вам нужно использовать зависимости, которые определяют, когда эффект должен быть запущен. Например, если вы хотите, чтобы эффект запускался только при изменении initialData, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
const Page = ({ initialData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await productListStore.fetchProductsFilters(query)
      productListStore.setProductsFilter(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [initialData]) // <-- массив зависимостей с initialData

  // render jsx...
}

export default observer(Page)
```

Comment: Второй параметр useEffect мне известен. Но как бы его не использовать это не избавляет от ошибки гидрации. Спасибо за информацию о startTransition. Хотелось бы раскрыть вопрос, о том есть ли более удобный способ наполнения стейта mobx при серверной загрузки данных.